# what format of configuration files gnu make can handle?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Today at work place I took a look at a project makefile that totally looked lile a yaml file configuration How I have used it in gitlab yaml configuration.

so my question is how many dfferent file configuration gnu make can handle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Today at work place I took a look at a project makefile that totally looked lile a yaml file configuration

Makefile syntax bears a resemblance to YAML.  It can be stronger or weaker depending on the makefile.  Points of general similarity include:

- The first line of a rule with one target and one prerequisite looks like a key / value pair in a YAML map.  This is especially pronounced in rules that do not specify a recipe.

  ```
  bar: bar.c

  foo.o: foo.c
  ```
- A rule with a target and no prerequisites, but with a recipe whose commands use error suppression, resembles a YAML map entry whose value is an array

  ```
  clean:
      -rm -r *.o bin/*
      -rmdir bin
  ```
- Make and YAML have substantially the same syntax for comments

  ```
  # This is a comment
  ```

> so my question is how many dfferent file configuration gnu make can handle ?

[The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#Top) documents only the one.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure that gnu make only takes more gnu make files for "configuration" - i.e.

`my_makefile.mk:`:

```
include config.mk

rule1:
    echo hello world
```

Where we can add some generic variable/rules into the "config.mk" file and include it in other makefiles. Can you point out where you have seen other gnu makefile "config" types that are not makefiles?